# Transition not working for translate3d

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code. When I click the toggle button, the push-wrap is supposed to slide to the right in 1 second. But the transition property doesn't seem to work.

```js
$('.btn').click(() => {
  $('body').toggleClass('showNav')
  return false
})
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.push-wrap {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  transition: translate3d 3s ease 0;


  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.showNav .push-wrap {
  transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrap">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>nav 1</li>
      <li>nav 2</li>
      <li>nav 3</li>
      <li>nav 4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="push-wrap">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button class="btn">toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `transition-duration: 1s;` to this css

```
.showNav .push-wrap {
  transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```js
$('.btn').click(() => {
  $('body').toggleClass('showNav')
  return false
})
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.push-wrap {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;

  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.showNav .push-wrap {
  transform: translate3d(300px, 0, 0);
 transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrap">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>nav 1</li>
      <li>nav 2</li>
      <li>nav 3</li>
      <li>nav 4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="push-wrap">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button class="btn">toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```